# Java synchronized method does not work as expected

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I did some research but I couldn't find right answer I guess.

```
public class MultiThreadTwo
{
    private int count = 0;
    public synchronized void increment() // I synchronized it here
    {
        count++;
    }
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        MultiThreadTwo app = new MultiThreadTwo();
        app.doWork();
    }
    public void doWork()
    {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run(){
                for (int i=0;i<100;i++ )
                    {
                        increment(); // increments
                    }
            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run()
            {
                for (int i=0;i<100;i++ )
                    {
                        increment(); // increments
                    }
            }
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        System.out.println("Count is : "+count);

        try
        {
            t1.join(); // wait for completes
            t2.join(); // wait for completes
        }catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

My output always diffrent like 200,182,171,65,140. How can I fix this I know I can check the value of count and if it is not the value I expected I can call the run again and again but It doesn't help me at all. synchronized keyword shouldn't fix that situation ?

What am I missing ?

**Solution :** Printing count after join fixed my problem.

Comment: what you expect the count to be ? also see `volatile`

Comment: volatile doesn't work either. count should be 200,

Comment: You should print the count after joining, not before (credits to user2040251 btw).

Comment: you print the result before the thread have completed their work. put the print after the joins.

Comment: join (wait for both threads to finish) before printing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you join the threads before priniting the result and make count volatile, you will always get 200.

Eventhough volatile does not harm here, it is not necessary. The accesses to count from t1 and t2 work properly because increment method is synchronized on the same object and calling join on a thread creates a happens-before relationship. Thus, the main thread is guaranteed to see a correct value of count even without volatile, too.

Comment: printing count after join fixed my problem thanks for your attention but, before this edit I was wrong volatile doesn't change anything I tried it times and times.

Comment: @Sneftel Why not?  This looks like the classic case of needing `volatile` - one thread can't rely on the value of `count` not being changed by the other thread, so it can't cache it in a register.  It seems to me that `volatile` is absolutely necessary.

Comment: @DavidWallace Both threads are `synchronized` on the same object.  `volatile` is not necessary.